# Find the expectation value and the variance of the time that the man is waiting for the bus in one month

Tags: probability

A man driving with a bus to his work $18$ times at month, there is a bus each $15$ minutes (integer minutes-floor,$\lfloor \text{minute}\rfloor$ )

> Find the expectation value and the variance of the time that the man is waiting for the bus in one month

My try:

Let as denote $i$ the day that the man is driving $1\leq i \leq18$, and let $X_i$ be a random variable such that $X_i\sim U(0,14)$ so $\mathbb{E}(X_i)=\frac{1}{15}(0+1+2+...+14)=\frac{105}{15}=7$

My attempt is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct, but you need variance too